# Applescript to return name of new file added to folder

Tags: applescript, folder-action

This is mostly a test so that I can work up to the function that I want to create down the line. I'm very new to AppleScript so bear with me!

I wrote this as an attempt to test a folder action that receives a new file and then displays an alert with the name of the newly added file.

This Script was saved to `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts`. And then assigned to a folder on my desktop called Return Name. I see the script run when a new item is dropped in but nothing happens.

Can anyone just explain to me what is wrong here?

Thanks!

```
on adding folder items to InputFolder after receiving NewItem
tell application "Finder"
    set FileName to name of NewItem
    activate
    display alert "New Items Added!" message ("File called " & FileName & " have been added" as string)
end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    delay 20 -- ALLOW MULTIPLES TO BE ADDED BEFORE PROCESSING - OPTIONAL
    set filesAdded to {}
    tell application "Finder" to set folderName to name of folder theFolder
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theNewItems
        set thisItem to item i of theNewItems
        tell application "Finder"
            set FileName to name of thisItem
            set end of filesAdded to (FileName & linefeed)
        end tell
    end repeat
    activate
    display alert "New Items Added!" message (("These Files Have Been Added To " & theFolder) & linefeed & linefeed & filesAdded as string)
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Thanks! So is the loop portion that you added required for such functions?

Comment: I don't think you need the delay.  Yes, you can get multiple items at once.